# Find a nearest points in the matrix with a specific different value

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a random matrix is A(n*n) (with values run continuously from 0 to pi). I chose a specific point S = A(randi(n), randi(n)), and I want to find the nearest point over which the different value of them is 1 radian (approximately) and then get the distance between them,

Then, I will run 1e6 times of the above process, and get the average value of above distances.

Till now, I do not have any idea about this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Especially when you provide no useful information in your question.

Comment: I just want to find an algorith for my problem. Sorry if my question is not clear.

Comment: @bigsony243 Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: How large is n?

Comment: @MBo: n = 100 for example.

Comment: i just want to know your algorith for this problem. I will update soon when I have something. I'm trying the simplest way.

Comment: One more question - what is "distance" here?

Comment: If you have miilion queries on the same 100x100 matrix, you can precalculate the closest good neighbors for every cell

Comment: What does `with values run continuously from 0 to pi` means in the context of a matrix (array of finite size, whereas values from 0 to pi are infinite in number)

Comment: @Mbo: sorry for clearness in my question. distance is sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)*delta (euclid distance) where (x1,y1) (x2,y2) are the coordinates of 2 points, delta is constant I set.

Comment: @fjardon: "A" can be declared like pi*rand(100). The different value can be approximately equal to 1.